# Linux grep command getting stuck in infinite loop while doing recurring search

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, infinite-loop

When trying to search for a pattern in files of current and subfolders, the `grep` command is stuck in an infinite loop.

The following illustrates the problem:

```
/results/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/work/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/work/work/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/work/work/work/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/work/work/work/work/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
/results/work/work/work/work/work/work/work/log/check_log:    if ($f1 eq 'dump') {
```

**Update:**
Adding the command used for reference.

```
sh -c 'grep --exclude=\*.{lst,txt} -srF dump *'
```

I am not quite sure what is causing this issue. I had searched in SOF and other forums, but this kind of infinite loop issue couldn't be found.

Any help in identifying the cause is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible loop in the file system (link somewhere to some parent directory). But where is grep involved? What is the exact command you used?

Comment: `ls -ld /results/work`, please?

Comment: As if `/results/work` pointed to `/results` somehow. Investigate this. In my Debian `grep -r` doesn't follow symlinks, `grep -R` does; your `grep` may vary (neither option is POSIX). What filesystem is this? Is it healthy?